# What is the significance of specific words used in Ephesians 6:12 to describe who our struggle is against?

Tags: word-study

We wrestle

- against principalities,
- against powers,
- against the rulers of the darkness of this age,
- against spiritual hosts of wickedness in the heavenly places.”
  ‭‭
  Ephesians‬ ‭6:12‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

Who or what are they and why does the author take the time to list them out?

Comment: I think the Greek might sound more like ‘rulerships’ in the English. Also why did you reassemble the verse?

Comment: Feel free to roll back the edit if you disagree with it or to change it.

Comment: Welcome to BH. It might be better to split this up and to take each item in turn in separate questions. Some of these items will be found dealt with in previously answered questions.Please take the Tour to see how we do things.

Comment: I have to agree with @NigelJ, each one of these listed is a separate question on its own

Comment: This text appears to me a quintessential Pauline piling of metaphors for emphasis.  They all refer to the same thing.  Splitting the question will start splitting hairs.

Comment: Those thinking of commanding others but we are only ruled by the words we say.

Comment: I have answered just two of the points, for the sake of brevity @Autodidact.

Answer (score 4):

Eph 6:12 should be read in the context of v10-17 where Paul is encouraging the Ephesian Christian community to use spiritual weapons to fight the spiritual battle against the "wiles of the devil" (v11).  In order to re-emphasise this spiritual battle, Paul describes these spiritual forces as "not blood and flesh" (see also Matt 16:17, 1 Cor 15:50, Heb 2:14), that is, non-human opponents in the battle.

Paul then describes these spiritual forces using four nouns or phrases:

- ἀρχάς (archas) = archons (David Bentley Hart), or rulers (BDAG), or chiefs
- ἐξουσίας (exousias) = authorities or bearers of ruling authority (BDAG).  This and the previous reference to rulers reminds us of Eph 2:2, John 12:31, 14:30, 16:11 which clearly point to Satan (as per Eph 6:11) as the person Paul had in mind.
- κοσμοκράτορας (kosmokratoras) = world rulers (BDAG), used here in the phrase, "world rulers of this darkness".  This is another reference to Satan and his minions.
- πνευματικὰ τῆς πονηρίας ἐν τοῖς ἐπουρανίοις = spiritual [forces] of evil in of the heavenly [things/places].  A similar phrase is used of Christ (Eph 1:3, 2:6) who blesses us in heavenly places.  But the reference in Eph 6:12 is, again, to Satan who is one of the evil forces against whom we battle.  See Luke 10:18 where Jesus describes Satan as falling from heaven.

Thus, Satan (v11) is described as a ruler, ruler of the world, and with authority who (at least) came from heavenly places.  A significant enemy indeed for which we must be properly equipped (v13-17), but Jesus is greater (Heb 1, etc.)

The thrust of Paul's argument here and in the rest of Ephesians is that Christ is more powerful than Satan and the rulers of darkness (Eph 1:3) because we need to have the spiritual armour to battle such spiritual forces of darkness (Eph 6:10-17).

This is quintessentially Paul who likes to describe things in a multiplicity of ways for emphasis.  We have Christ who is all-powerful and stronger than Satan who is (for the moment) ruler of this world (Eph 2:2, John 12:31, 14:30, 16:11); and we need to have the full armour of God to battle this mighty foe - truth, righteousness, gospel of peace, faith, and salvation based on the word of God.

Comment: It’s a great generalization response, you did a good job but I am one for splitting hairs especially if the text splits them first. If it were merely satan and his “minions” then the text would not have felt the need to elaborate. But it’s ranking based, territorial based and it draws together OT references so we can know that this is an age old issue but under a new circumstance the New Covenant. It’s important also to consider all the OT passages therefore like Deu 32:8,43, psalm 82, 89, Daniel. All the divine council language and when these took their ranks in history. Know your enemy!

Comment: Take for instance *“And the devil (διαβολος) said to Him, “All this authority (εξουσιαν) I will give You, and their glory; for this has been delivered to me, and I give it to whomever I wish.”
‭‭Luke‬ ‭4:6* when was it delivered to him exactly? Jesus doesn’t deny that this was true. In Ephesians 6:11 it speaks of the wiles (μεθοδειας) of the διαβολος and then in verse 12 it describes these wiles or methodologies split into four categories. εξουσιαν is one of them there are three others

Comment: I've upvoted as a means of clearing the question and getting it answered. But I disagree with the over-simplification that the apostle is merely 'piling metaphors'. Each description is accurately describing a different aspect of the spiritual authorities in the heavens which will, at the end of time, be deposed.

Comment: @Nigel J - why not proffer an answer of your own?

Comment: Personally I won’t be answering this question because it’s too big of a subject that draws from a very deep well. It will take at a minimum establishing a baseline of origin for these categories, so as not to run the risk of either being downvoted for insufficient supporting references or constantly answering qualifying questions. For that reason I’m going to upvote your response. But I too disagree that Apostle Paul is piling. Writing was expensive, he didn’t have the luxury of piling, he had to be as concise as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement @Mac'sMusings. I have done as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be brief, I am considering just the first two items 'principalities and powers'.

'Principalities' is from ἀρχὰς [Strong 746](https://biblehub.com/greek/archas_746.htm) which is derived from ἀρχὴ [Strong 746](https://biblehub.com/greek/arche__746.htm) which is usually translated 'beginning' in the KJV. In the beginning God created the heavens ... plural.

The heavenly beings which are the beginning of God's creation precede humanity. And, in the first creation, they rule above humanity. They are the sons of God mentioned in the second chapter of Job.

That such precedent and powerful beings should contend with mortal men regarding spiritual matters is a fearsome thought. We know how successful such a being was in Eden, cunningly approaching the woman and deceiving her in order to prompt the man to transgress and thus bringing the whole of humanity, then and subsequently, under his spiritual power using Law to do so.

The scope of the word is of something not only foundational in precedence but also of progressive authority to appoint others beneath, in order to form a structure of government.

'Powers' is the word  ἐξουσίας [Strong 1849](https://biblehub.com/greek/exousias_1849.htm). Paul uses this word when he says that the potter has power over the clay, Romans 9:21 and, significantly, Diabolos uses the same word when he tempts Jesus, showing him 'all the kingdoms of the world in a moment of time', saying :

> All this power will I give thee and the glory of them Luke 4:6 KJV.

Jesus does not dispute the tempter's ability to do as he promises. Rather he tells him to 'Get thee behind me' denying his worship when the Entity, by his offer, reveals whom he really is - 'the god of this age' II Corinthians 4:4.

Who can stand if such immense spiritual Beings - not just the one leading Entity, but others with him - should tempt, influence, infiltrate, bear down upon and crush a human soul ?

But the remarkable thing about this text, Ephesians 6:12, and the preceding similar text, Ephesians 1:21, is that Paul has *already shown previously* that the battle is won and there is nothing to fear.

For before even the precedence of the archetypal entities of the heavens, God has :

> chosen us in [Christ] before the foundation of the *kosmos* Ephesians 1:4.

And as to their lawful, proper authority, their ability to command and control, their irresistible power within their own realm, this has already been overturned by him who is able to :

> gather together, in one, all things in Christ both which are in heaven, and which are on earth ... Ephesians 1:10

Both elect angels (I Timothy 5:21) and redeemed men are gathered together into the realm of Christ, escaped (by lawful redemption) from the realm of the principalities and powers ... for :

> having spoiled principalities and powers, he made a shew of them openly, triumphing over them ... Colossians 2:15 KJV.

Answer (score 1):

A 4th century Greek Church Father, John Chrysostom (d. 407), explained the Greek in Greek in his [*12th Homily on the Epistle to the Ephesians*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf113.iii.iv.xxiii.html).  The opponents listed in the text are (nominative case):

- αἱ ἀρχαί (*ai archai*): **the *principalities*** (the Greek includes the definite article)
- αἱ ἐξουσίαι (*ai exousiai*): ***the powers***
- οἱ κοσμοκράτορες  τοῦ σκότους τοῦ αἰῶνος τούτου (*oi kosmokratores to skotous tou aiōnos toutou*): ***the rulers*** ("cosmocrats") ***of the darkness of this world*** (or *age* - *aeon*).  The word *κοσμοκράτορ* only appears here in the New Testament, no where in the Old Testament (Septuagint), and [very rarely in Greek literature](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkosmokra%2Ftwr).
- τὰ πνευματικὰ τῆς πονηρίας ἐν τοῖς ἐπουρανίοις (*ta pneumatika tēs ponērias en tois epouraniois*):  ***the spiritual*** [things; NKJV: hosts] ***of wickedness in the heavens*** (i.e. "high places")

---

*The principalities* (αἱ ἀρχαί) and *the powers* (αἱ ἐξουσίαι) echoes Colossians 1:16:

> *For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him*

Colossians refers, however, to angels, whereas Paul here is referring to demonic counterparts.

---

The expression *en tois epouraniois*, translated as *in high places* in the King James Bible, literally means "in the heavenlies":  ἐπουράνιος (*epouranios*) is an adjective.  Chrysostom - again, a Greek explaining Greek Scripture to Greeks - explains the usage:

> The expression “in the heavenlies” (ἐν τοῖς ἐπουρανίοις) is equivalent to, “for the heavenly things.” It is not that they may gain anything by the conquest, but that they may despoil us. As if one were to say, “In what does the contract lie?” In gold. The word “in,” means, “in behalf of”; the word “in” (ἐν) also means [something like] “on account” Observe how the power of the enemy startles us; how it makes us all circumspection, to know that the hazard is on behalf of vast interests, and the victory for the sake of great rewards. For he is doing his best to cast us out of Heaven.

---

Regarding the the reference to darkness in  *rulers of the darkness*, Chrysostom explains:

> What darkness? Is it that of night? No, but of wickedness. *For ye were*, saith he, *once darkness* Ephesians 5:8); so naming that wickedness which is in this present life; for beyond it, it will have no place, not in Heaven, nor in the world to come.

---

The *rulers* of said darkness - the "cosmocrats" - are explained:

> “World-rulers” he calls them, not as having the mastery over the world, but the Scripture is wont to call wicked practices “the world,” as, for example, where Christ saith, *They are not of this world, even as I am not of the world.* (John 17:16). What then, were they not of the world? Were they not clothed with flesh? Were they not of those who are in the world? And again; *The world hateth Me, but you it cannot hate* (John 7:7) ... the Apostle here by *the world* means wicked men, and the evil spirits have more especial power over them

---

In his homily, Chrysostom adds a lesson:

> If then it is a warfare, if such are the forces arrayed against us, if “the principalities” are incorporeal, if they are “rulers of the world,” if they are “the spiritual hosts of wickedness,” how, tell me, canst thou live in self-indulgence? How canst thou be dissolute? How if we are unarmed, shall we be able to overcome? These words let every one repeat to himself every day, whenever he is under the influence of anger, or of lust, whenever he is aiming, and all to no profit, after this languid life. Let him hearken to the blessed Paul, saying to him, “Our wrestling is not against flesh and blood, but against the principalities, against the powers.” A harder warfare this than that which is matter of sense, a fiercer conflict. Think how long time this enemy is wrestling, for what it is that he is fighting, and be more guarded than ever. “Nay,” a man will say, “but as he is the devil, he ought to have been removed out of the way, and then all had been saved.” These are the pretenses to which some of your indolent ones in self-defense give utterance. When thou oughtest to be thankful, O man, that, if thou hast a mind, thou hast the victory over such a foe, thou art on the contrary even discontented, and givest utterance to the words of some sluggish and sleepy soldier. Thou knowest the points of attack, if thou choosest.

---

(As an aside, Ephesians 6:10-17 is one of the Scriptures that is read during the service of tonsuring an Eastern Orthodox monk)